# Theme My Login - error with redirect

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect

I need to optimize my WordPress page, and have this little problem: when I click log in, the address bar shows the following URL:

http://www.elefantti.iq.pl/zaloguj/?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.elefantti.iq.pl%2F

How can I achieve an effect like this:

http://www.elefantti.iq.pl/zaloguj/ ?

I have tried some plugins like Pretty Link but they don't work.

Can somebody help me solve this problem?

Comment: How about this? https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-login-url/

Comment: this dont work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That URL is hardcoded with ZALOGUJ button:

[image]

You need to change the URL to http://www.elefantti.iq.pl/zaloguj/ because it obviously does work.

EDIT. Quick and dirty fix:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { echo '<a href="'.wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ).'" title="Wyloguj" class="zaloguj">Wyloguj</a>'; } else { echo '<a href="/zaloguj" title="Zaloguj" class="zaloguj">Zaloguj</a>'; } ?>
```

Comment: Sorry but i dont get it ...  I see your screen . But "zaloguj" is made by Theme My Login . Where i must change it , in WP panel or theme code ?
Can you explain it to me this simpler

Comment: In theme code. But I can't tell you where exactly without seeing your theme code.

Comment: I found this in WP editor :

<?php
 if ( is_user_logged_in() ) 
{
 echo '<a href="'.wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ).'" title="Wyloguj" class="zaloguj">Wyloguj</a>';
     } else {
         echo '<a href="'.wp_login_url( get_permalink() ).'" title="Zaloguj" class="zaloguj">Zaloguj</a>';
     }
     ?>

But i not to good i php .

Comment: Tell me what exactly i need to copy you to solve this problem .

Comment: Quick and dirty: `<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { echo '<a href="'.wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ).'" title="Wyloguj" class="zaloguj">Wyloguj</a>'; } else { echo '<a href="/zaloguj" title="Zaloguj" class="zaloguj">Zaloguj</a>'; } ?>`

Comment: Ok , its work . Perfect Thank , You very Much . It was very urgent for me.

Have a nice day

Comment: Where can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');` to your themes functions.php file.

Comment: this dont work for me . I copy/past Like you said and nothing happen .